# How to get object value?

Tags: magento2, price, bundled-product

How to get amount value from the below code.

```
Magento\Framework\Pricing\Amount\Base Object
(
    [amount:protected] => 2520
    [baseAmount:protected] => 
    [totalAdjustmentAmount:protected] => 
    [adjustmentAmounts:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [adjustments:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I have try below but no luck

```
//print_r($amount->amount); exit;
```

Comment: try `echo $yourobject->getAmount();`

Comment: not work return empty

Comment: same result empty

Comment: try  
echo $obj->getAmount()->getValue();  (or)
echo $obj->getValue();

Comment: I have added the simplest one !

Comment: @ManishGoswami Thanks for replying on this. but i got already solution. Question is too old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `$amount` is this object, use:

```
$amount->getValue();
```

### How to find out by yourself:

Look at the source code of [`Magento\Framework\Pricing\Amount\Base`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Pricing/Amount/Base.php) and search for `$this->amount`. If you find a method that **returns** the value, you're done.

And there it is:

```
/**
 * Return full amount value
 *
 * @param null|string|array $exclude
 * @return float
 */
public function getValue($exclude = null)
{
    if ($exclude === null) {
        return $this->amount;
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($yourobject->getData());
```

and check what you are getting.

Or you can try like

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r(get_class_methods($yourobject));
```

It will give you all available methods available in this object, and you can try any of that method.

Answer (score 0):

ok you can do below hack that is always work for me

convert your object into json

```
   $json = json_encode($object);
```

then convert your json to array

```
 $array = json_decode($json, true);
 print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Magento\Framework\Phrase Object
        (
            [text:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => "%fieldName" is required. Enter and try again.
            [arguments:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => Array
                (
                    [fieldName] => street
                )

        )

    [1] => Magento\Framework\Phrase Object
        (
            [text:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => "%fieldName" is required. Enter and try again.
            [arguments:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => Array
                (
                    [fieldName] => city
                )

        )

    [2] => Magento\Framework\Phrase Object
        (
            [text:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => "%fieldName" is required. Enter and try again.
            [arguments:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => Array
                (
                    [fieldName] => postcode
                )

        )

)
```

I was getting this and I got the value like this.

```
$errors[0]->getArguments()['fieldName']
```

Or

```
foreach ($errors as $error){
   $value = $error->getArguments()['fieldName'];
}
```